# Java processes keep runnning after I quit applications (VS Code, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am on **ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** and use **VS Code** and **Android Studio** for mobile app development.

When I quit the vs code or android studio, **a couple of java processes keep running and take RAM storage**. I have to kill them manually each time.

Is it a normal behavior? Because sometimes these processes fill up my memory usage and system hangs. Please advise.